# How to get a python github code made for windows to run on macos

Tags: python

To be clear - I'm not trying to write code or edit someone else's code. Someone made a brilliant program for something I'm interested in on github but it's designed for windows and I'm on a mac.

I've basically been crash-coursing in python just to figure out how to load it all but while the developer says it should run on other systems than windows, it isn't working as the desktop app appears to be working on a cmd file.

I got the file to run as a .command file but when it loads as a Terminal it's giving me

```
Path/file-main/file.command: line 1: @echo: command not found
Path/file-main/file.command: line 9: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
Path/file-main/file.command: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I'm honestly not sure what to do as all. I know basics but this level of script is beyond my skill level so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a batch file, not Python.

Comment: Depending on how it's written, it may not be possible.

Comment: @Keith The original github file is from here https://github.com/nianeyna/ao3downloader and the directions were to download Python. If it's not doable it's not doable I'm just trying to figure out what - if anything - I can do. Thank you for taking a look anyway.

Comment: Looks like it's portable, so it should run. What you are running is the Windows launcher script that creates a virtual environment and then runs it.

Comment: If you type "python3" what do you see?

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Just throw out the `.cmd` file.  That's a Windows batch file, because 90% of their users are on Windows.  Run the `.py`.

Comment: @Keith python3 got python to load with the existing updates instead of 2.7 - it needed the dependency as well. I was also able to contact the author of the script who helped me on a few script-specific things but these adjustments worked really well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to run the .cmd file if you're on mac, as long as you've installed python ([here's a guide to how to do that, if you haven't already](https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/osx/)). Thereafter, you should just be able to run the program directly, after installing the relevant dependencies. After downloading the repository and going inside it with the command line (in the top-level folder of the repo), run the following commands:

First, install dependencies:

```sh
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

then, once that's done, execute the program

```sh
python ao3downloader.py
```

and the program's instructions should guide you through the rest.

You may have to try `pip3` and `python3` instead, if the above doesn't work.

Comment: turns out "python3" is what I needed to make this run! Thank you so much everyone who helped me! - macos was dead set on executing 2.7 even though that is not what i installed and it was screwing everything up -_- the pip install requirements was needed too. Thank you so much. Hopefully I'll be able to do this myself next time I want to load a script.